# Save as .PARQUET file in Logic App workflow

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How can I save the output file from **Run query and list results** in a **.PARQUET** file format.

This is my current workflow.

[image]

*My Logic App is working, **But the file .parquet created are not valid every time I view it on Apache Parquet Viewer***

Can someone help me on this matter. Thank you!

Output:
[image]

Comment: Have you observed any particular cases when it is not valid?

Comment: Thanks for the response @SwethaKandikonda-MT what do you mean particular cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to add .parquet to the csv file you are receiving but that's not how it will be converted to parquet file.

One of the workarounds that you can try is to get the csv file and then add Azure function which can convert into parquet file and then adding the azure function to logic app.

Here is the function that worked for me:

```cs
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("<YOUR CONNECTION STRING>");
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("<YOUR CONTAINER NAME>");
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("sample.csv");

//Download the blob
Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\<USER NAME>\source\repos\ParquetConsoleApp\ParquetConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\" + blobClient.Name);
await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(file);
Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
file.Close();
            
//Read the downloaded blob
Stream file1 = new FileStream(blobClient.Name, FileMode.Open);
Console.WriteLine(file1.ReadToEnd());
file1.Close();

//Convert to parquet
ChoParquetRecordConfiguration csv = new ChoParquetRecordConfiguration();
using (var r = new ChoCSVReader(@"C:\Users\<USER NAME>\source\repos\ParquetConsoleApp\ParquetConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\" + blobClient.Name))
{
        using (var w = new ChoParquetWriter(@"C:\Users\<USER NAME>\source\repos\ParquetConsoleApp\ParquetConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\convertedParquet.parquet"))
        {
            w.Write(r);
            w.Close();
         }
}
```

after this step you can publish to your azure function and add the Azure function connector to your logic app

You can skip the first 2 steps (i.e.. Read and Download the blob) and get the blob directly from logic app and send it to your azure function and follow the same method as above. The generated parquet file will be in this path.

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\source\repos\ParquetConsoleApp\ParquetConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\convertedParquet.parquet
```

Here `convertedParquet.parquet` is the name of the parquet file. Now you can read the converted parquet file in Apache Parquet reader.

Here is the output

[image]